# Traversing a list and comparing elements

Tags: python-3.x

I am traversing a list of binary elements.  When I get to the fourth and subsequent elements, what happens depends on what was in the list before.

Please look at my code and see if you can help me figure out why it is not looking at the proper indices. My program takes up at the fourth element in the list.  u is a tally of all unique subsets.  Sometimes, the elements in u must be used in the calculation for the next item appended into u.

I am new to all of this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#Computer will read each element after the third element, one at a time, and 
#evaluate the element itself and how it relates to the previous elements.
#if next element is same as the element before, then computer returns the 
#same number to the list as the calculation before.
#If the next element is not the same as the element before, then computer 
#returns the sum of the last two calculations entered into the list.
#If the next element is not the same as the element before, but is coming 
#off of two same elements, then computer returns the sum of the last three 
#calculations in the list into the list.
#If element is a new element, then computer returns a 1 to the list.

if index > 2:
    print ("These are the next terms.")

    r = int (u[-1])
    s = int (u[-2])
    t = int (u[-3])
    w = [r,s]
    q = [r,s,t]

    print ("This element is: ", element)
    if element in L[:-1]: #if seen before
        print ("this element has been seen before")
        if element == L[-2]: #same as previous element
            print("this element is the same as the previous element")
            u.append(u[-1])
            print(u)
        else: #not same as previous
            if L[-2] != L[-3]:
                print("this element is NOT the same as the previous element")
                u.append(sum(w))
                print(u)
            else:
                if element != L[-2]:# not same, happened before, off of 2 identicals
                    if element in L[:-1]:
                        if L[-2]==L[-3]:
                            print("this element is not the same, coming off two identicals")
                            u.append(sum(q))
                            print (sum(q))
                            print (u)             
    else:
        if element != L[:]: #not the same as previous, but NEW
            print("this element is NEW!")
            u.append(sum(q) + 1)
            print (u)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: It might help if you assign values for `index`, `u`, `element`, and `L` at the beginning of your example code.